# Redis/Mongo Sorted list complexity

Tags: mongodb, sorting, redis, sortedlist, sortedset

I know it's not a fair comparison, but my question is theoretically about the complexity of operations.

Redis (sorted set)-

- ZADD - Time complexity: O(log(N)) where N is the number of elements
  in the sorted set.
- ZRANGE - Time complexity: O(log(N)+M) with N
  being the number of elements in the sorted set and M the number of
  elements returned.

What would be the Mongo equivalent on a sorted array:

```
{
   sorted_list : [{name : <string>,score : <Number>}]
}

collection.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
       sorted_list: {
         $each: [ { name: 3, score: 8 }, { name: 4, score: 7 }, { name: 5, score: 6 } ],
         $sort: { score: 1 }
       }
     }
   }
)

collection.find( { _id: 1}, { sorted_list: { $slice: [ 20, 10 ] } } )
```

What is the complexity of the `update` and `find` operations?

Moreover, my aim is to find a solution where the "read" operation (pull from an index in the sorted list), will be optimal - O(1). And still have an O(log(N)) insertion. That should be viable by utilizing memory (have an array copy of the sorted set).
Is there a platform which implement it?

Comment: Congratulations. I could not think of a better way to get my question closed than to invite a war between MongoDB and Redis Fan boys. Don't mark questions like this. It never works out well.

Comment: @NeilLunn , I beleive my question is very specific about the theoretical differences between both DBs implementations. 
If you have a better suggestion for the title I would be happy to edit it.

Comment: Still waiting for a constructive comment...

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented zadd and zrange for a project in mongodb although I didn't store the sorted set elements in an embedded array.

The problem I had with embedded arrays is that there was no easy way to make sure elements were unique. In your case someone can zadd another element with the same name but with a different score. In this case redis just updates the score of the element and doesn't add a new element.

So instead of using an embedded array I made each sorted set element a new document in the following form.

```
{
 _key: "sortedSetKey",
 value: "value1",
 score: 12
},
{
 _key: "sortedSetKey",
 value: "value2"
 score: 3
}
```

There are 2 compound indices on the collection for `{_key: 1, score: -1}` and `{_key: 1, value: -1}`.

With all of this in place adding a new element to a sorted set becomes :

```
db.objects.update({
  _key: key, value: value
}, {
   $set: {
     score: parseInt(score, 10)
   }
}, { upsert: true });
```

This will be O(log(n)) since there is an index on (key, value).

Getting a range is a bit more complex :

```
db.objects.find({_key: key}, {fields: {_id: 0, value: 1})
    .limit(stop - start + 1)
    .skip(start)
    .sort({score: sort})
```

Again this uses the key index to find all the elements that belong to a sorted set and then sorts on the score field so the compound index is used. The limit and skip is used to grab a portion of the sorted set. Obviously this won't be O(1). If you pass in higher values of skip in a large sorted set it will scan many documents.

Hope that gives some ideas.

You can check the full source [here](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/blob/master/src/database/mongo/sorted.js)

Comment: Interesting! 1. I didn't mind that it's not a unique set , that's why I used the list. But your implementation seems better. 2. As you mentioned, in this case it's should be O(stop). I wonder if the "$slice" operation can be O(limit)?

Comment: If you are always grabbing the first N elements of the sorted set, ie if you are using start=0 and stop=n then it is O(stop) but as you increase start it will scan more and more documents.

Comment: Of course. I guessed u meant {stop= skip+limit} and that's why I wrote O(stop). Anyway, now my concern is what is the complexity of "$slice". If no answer will be given here, I will close this question and open a new one.

Comment: Opened a new question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917739/mongo-slice-complexity