# Mongo sorted list complexity

Tags: mongodb, sortedlist

For the following sorted list:

```
{
   sorted_list : [{name : <string>,score : <Number>}]
}
```

What are the complexities of the following commands (in 'O' notations)?

Find:

```
collection.find( { _id: 1}, { sorted_list: { $slice: [ <skip>, <limit> ] } } )
```

Insert:

```
collection.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
       sorted_list: {
         $each: [ { name: 3, score: 8 }, { name: 4, score: 7 }, { name: 5, score: 6 } ],
         $sort: { score: 1 }
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Remove:

```
collection.update({"sorted_list.name": name},{ $pull: { "sorted_list.name": <name> } },{ multi: true });
```

**EDIT**

Let's assume ther following index exists:

`{ "sorted_list.name" : 1}`

Comment: There are three operations here. The find and Remove are fairly straightforward as one uses recorded indicies and the other can also be variably affected by indexed content (so can the update for that matter). If there is a question here then it appears to be more about the update. As in the effect of introducing `n` values into an exiting list of `x` elements and executing the sort. You do realize that growing documents in MongoDB without allocated space means they physically move. Probably should be more of your concern than mapping the complexity.

Comment: So, to sum it up: Find - O(skip+limit). Remove(with regard to the index) - O(n) where n is the number of records in list.Update - still remains a question. As for allocating space, you are probably right but that's for a separate question.

Comment: It's actually the more important question. Complexity theory is not really going to solve anything for you other than homework assignments. But aside from me pointing out your question is "three" questions, there is.. 1. "Did I mention array values with indicies? Yes I think. 2. Meat of the question but pointed out what you should be asking. 3. Variable on too many factors. Others may vary but I for one are not personally impressed by those who want to prove they just completed a computing science or math unit. Solving real problems is more the thing here.